# Как сделать расчет стоимости заказа?

Tags: java, map

Имеется map с ценами <наименование, цена> и map с заказом <наименование, количество>. Нужно рассчитать общую стоимость заказа. Цена в doble.  Наименование String.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static double toCalculatePrice(Map<String, Double> database, Map<String, Integer> order) {
    double price = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : order.entrySet()) {
        if(database.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            price += database.get(entry.getKey()) * order.get(entry.getKey());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // или ваше исключение
        }
    }
    return price;
}
```

Тест:

```
Map<String, Double> database = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
database.put("Carrot", 15.2);
database.put("Milk", 20.5);
order.put("Carrot", 20);

System.out.println(toCalculatePrice(database, order));
```

Выведет:

> 304.0

Однако, советую использовать BigDecimal, так как double может неверно считать, что для приложений с подсчетом денег не допустимо

Comment: с ценами в double нужно работать аккуратно, например, есть цена товара 3.3 ед. в количестве 3 шт., в результате будет `9.899999999999999`

Comment: Да, я знаю. Указал этот момент.